# Adding Style to image gallery description

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, title

Please help : i need to add a style to description of an image using

or  add a title before the description

this is my html

```
<div ><img src='images/1s.jpg' data-big-src='images/1.jpg' />

      <p >image title</p>
      <p >image description</p>
</div>
```

or even just add a space between each

or a line :
this is the code

```
jQuery.fn.easyGallery = function() {

if ($(this).length > 1) {
$.each($(this), function(key, val) {
   new sliderObject($('.' + val.className + ':eq( ' + key + ')'));
  });
 } else {
new sliderObject($(this));
}
function sliderObject(instance) {
var children = instance.find('img'),
        imageText = '',
        countImages = children.length,
        sliderBackground = $('<div class="ligthbox_background"></div>'),
        sliderWrap = $('<div class="ligthbox_wrap"></div>'),
        sliderImageSrc = '',
        sliderImage = $('<img></img>'),
        btnForward = $('<div class="ligthbox_weiter"></div>'),
        btnBack = $('<div class="ligthbox_zurueck"></div>'),
        btnCollaction = [],
        activeItemOrder = 0,
        activeText = '',
        lightboxText = $('<p id="ligthbox_text"></p>'),
        sliderActive = 0,
        animationSpeed = 50,
        callBlock = 0;

var getImageDescription = function (imageObject) {
  var textObject = [];
  $.each(imageObject, function(index, val) {
    if ($(this).siblings('p').length > 0) {
      textObject[index] = $(this).siblings('p');
    } else {
      textObject[index] = '';
    }
  });
  return textObject;
}

var handleBtnCollaction = function(order) {
  btnForward.remove();
  btnBack.remove();
  if (activeItemOrder === 0) {
    btnCollaction = [btnForward];
  }
  else if (activeItemOrder === countImages - 1) {
    btnCollaction = [btnBack];
  } else {
    btnCollaction = [btnForward, btnBack];
  }
};

var generateArrows = function() {
  $.each(btnCollaction, function(key, val) {
    sliderWrap.append(val);
  });
};

var generateSilderHtml = function() {
  sliderBackground.append(sliderWrap);
  sliderWrap.append(sliderImage.attr('src', sliderImageSrc), lightboxText.html(activeText));

  slideAnimation(animationSpeed);
};

var changeSldierText = function() {
  activeText = imageText[activeItemOrder].length > 0 ? imageText[activeItemOrder].text() : '';

  lightboxText.html(activeText);
}

var nextImage = function() {
  if (activeItemOrder > 0) {
    activeItemOrder--;
    changeSldierText();
    handleBtnCollaction();
    sliderImageSrc = $(children[activeItemOrder]).attr('data-big-src');

    sliderImage.one("load", function() {
      slideAnimation();
    }).attr("src", sliderImageSrc);
  }
};

var prevImage = function() {
  if (activeItemOrder < (countImages - 1)) {
    activeItemOrder++;
    changeSldierText();
    handleBtnCollaction();
    sliderImageSrc = $(children[activeItemOrder]).attr('data-big-src');

    sliderImage.one("load", function() {
      slideAnimation();
    }).attr("src", sliderImageSrc);

  }
};

var slideAnimation = function(speed) {
  generateArrows();
  var tempo = tempo ? tempo : 500;
  if (sliderImage.width() > 0) {
    sliderWrap.animate({
      width: sliderImage.width() + 160,
    }, speed, function() {
      sliderImage.css("opacity", "1");
      callBlock = 0;
    });
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(slideAnimation, tempo, 500);
  }
};

$.each(children, function(key, child) {
  children[key].itemOrder = key;
});

var slider = {
  init: function() {

    if (!sliderActive) {
      $(children).click(function() {
        sliderImageSrc = $(this).attr('data-big-src');
        activeItemOrder = this.itemOrder;

        imageText = getImageDescription(children);
        activeText = imageText[activeItemOrder].length > 0 ? imageText[activeItemOrder].text() : '';

        handleBtnCollaction();
        generateSilderHtml();
        slider.startSlider();
      });

      sliderActive = 1;
    } else {
      console.error('slider error');
      clearSlider();
    }
  },
  startSlider: function() {
    $('body').append(sliderBackground);

    var initEvents = function() {

      sliderBackground.on('click', '.ligthbox_zurueck', function() {
        if (!callBlock) {
          callBlock = 1;
          sliderImage.css('opacity', '0');
          nextImage();
        }
      });

      sliderBackground.on('click', '.ligthbox_weiter', function() {
        if (!callBlock) {
          callBlock = 1;
          sliderImage.css('opacity', '0');
          prevImage();
        }
      });

      $('.ligthbox_background').click(function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.className === sliderBackground.attr('class')) {
          clearSlider();
        }
      });

      $(document).bind("keypress.esc", function(ev) {
        if (ev.keyCode == 27) {
          clearSlider();
        }
      });

    };

    var clearSlider = function() {
      sliderBackground.off(); //unbind all slider-events
      $(document).unbind("keypress.esc"); //unbind keypress-event for namespace esc
      sliderBackground.animate({height: 0, width: 0}, 700, function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
        sliderImage.remove();
        lightboxText.remove();
        sliderWrap.remove();
        sliderBackground.remove();
        sliderImageSrc = 0;
        btnCollaction = [];
        sliderActive = 0;
      });
    }
    sliderBackground.animate({width: "100%"}, 300, function() {
      initEvents();
    });
  }
};

slider.init();
}
};
```

Comment: have you tried adding just a <br/> tag to where you want a line break?

Comment: yes and it didnt work .

Comment: it doesnt take anything but <p> tagged